# How would you serve a Google cloud storage file from an appengine servlet?

Tags: google-app-engine, jakarta-ee, google-cloud-storage

The user uploaded some files, that I stored in Google Cloud Storage. Now the user comes back and want to download a file from a list my app is showing. He/she clicks the link and a servlet is called. What the code behind that servlet would look like?
Also, I don't want to make the objects publicly available.
Here how mine would look like: 
Is there a simpler way to do this?
Thanks.

```
public class ServeGSObject extends HttpServlet {
    FileService fileService = FileServiceFactory.getFileService();
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
        String fullFilePath = request.getParameter("objectPath");
        AppEngineFile file = new AppEngineFile(fullFilePath);
        try {
            FileReadChannel channel = fileService.openReadChannel(file, false);
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(Channels.newInputStream(channel));
            BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=\"" + file.getNamePart() + "");
            int b = 0;
            while((b = bis.read()) != -1) {
                bos.write(b);
            }
            bos.flush();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are your user authenticated using Google Accounts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate a temporary `blobKey` corresponding to your Google Storage file using [`blobstoreService.createGsBlobKey`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/blobstore/BlobstoreService#createGsBlobKey%28java.lang.String%29)

And serve it like a regular blobstore file, using [`blobstoreService.serve(blobKey, res)`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/overview#Serving_a_Blob)
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/overview#Serving_a_Blob

Comment: But isn't it ineffective to call createGsBlobKey for a static file, especially if you want to serve that file many times?